# Teams resource limitation for /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages change notification subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to implement Change Notification subscription for Teams Resource(/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages).

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#teams-resource-limitations-preview) stats the following limitations.

`A maximum of 10000 active subscriptions per organization on chats and channels for all applications is allowed.`

Does that mean : If we have a multi-tenant application then the total number of active subscriptions,all tenants combined can only be 10000 ?

Comment: what do you mean by "user typed message"?,the message included in API or the message users send it team?

Comment: pls seperate out your question one question per thread

Comment: Thanks @Maghilvannan It is the message posted by the User.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific: if you have a multi-tenant application, your application will be able to create up to 10000 per tenant it is installed in. This assumes each tenant doesn't have any other application subscribing to teams chat and channel messages.
If you have your application in 5 tenants, it'll be able to create up to 50 000 subscriptions (to a limit of 10k per tenant, capacity on one tenant is not transferable to another)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the maximum amount of active subscriptions per organization is 10000